# Nav doesn't hide when i click on menu (cursor pointer)

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my `menuBtn` doesn't work on my site. The navigationbar is still visible on the site. When I investigate the site on Chrome, the value of the `sideNav.style.right` changes, but the nav-bar is still there.

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------    Head    -------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*------------    Background    -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 3, 3, 0.422),rgba(4, 3, 3, 0.422)) , url(pic/background.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------    Logo    -------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.logo{
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;  
    z-index: 2;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*------------    Home / Text    ----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.banner_text{
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.banner_text h1{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    background: url(pic/text_background_new_low.png);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip:text;
    background-position: 0 200px;
    background-size: -20%;
    animation: back 20s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes back{
    100%{
        background-position: 3000px 0;
    }
}
.banner_text p{
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------    Contact us Button    ------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.contact{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.contact a{
    width:190px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: black;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to right  , gold 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.197) 65%)right;
    background-size: 300% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    color: white;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.contact a:hover{
    background-position:left;
    color:black;  
}
.lover{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;    
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------   EFFECTS   -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.slide-left{
    animation: slide-left 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slide-left{
    0% {
        transform: translate(100px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#p.slide-left{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.contact.slide-left{
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------   Navigation   -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#sideNav{
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #0000007f;
}
.sideNav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sideNav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 48px;
}
#sideNav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------   Navigation / Animation   ---------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#sideNav ul li a:hover{
    color: gold;
}
#sideNav ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ffd700;
    display: block;
    margin: auto; 
    transition: 0.2s;
}
#sideNav ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffd700;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------   Hamburger Menu   ------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#menuBtn{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
#menuBtn img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------   Responsive   ----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width:770px){
    .sideNav ul{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 75px;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    #sideNav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #sideNav ul li a{
        color: white;
    }
    .banner_text h1{
        font-size:70px;
    }
    .banner_text p{
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    #menuBtn{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Autohaus Kaya</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="zzzAutohaus_Kaya.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            html{
                scroll-behavior: smooth;
                scrollbar-width: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="banner">
            <img src="pic/logo.png" class="logo">
            <div id="sideNav">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Inzahlungnahme & Finanzierung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="menuBtn">
                <img src="pic/hamburger_icon.png">
            </div>
            <script>
                var menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
                var sideNav= document.getElementById("sideNav")
                var menu = document.getElementById("menu")

                menuBtn.onclick = function(){
                    if(sideNav.style.right == "-250px"){
                        sideNav.style.right = "0";
                    }
                    else{
                        sideNav.style.right = "-250px";
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <div class="banner_text slide-left">
                <h1>Willkommen</h1>
                <p class="slide-left">Gemeinsam finden wir Ihr passendes Wunschfahrzeug. Durch langjährige Erfahrung in der Automobilbranche wissen wir, 
                    worauf Sie Wert legen. Lassen Sie sich gerne bei einem Kalt - oder Warmgetränk überzeugen und vereinbaren Sie jetzt 
                    einen Termin.</p>
                <div class="contact slide-left">
                    <a href="#" class="lover">Kontaktieren Sie uns</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has something to do with `left:0;` already defining `#sideNav`. So instead of trying to alter the `right` with your JS code, try altering the `left` instead.  Something like this:

```
                menuBtn.onclick = function(){
                if(sideNav.style.left == "800px"){
                    sideNav.style.left = "0";
                }
                else{
                    sideNav.style.left = "800px";
                }
            }
```

Here's a demonstrations of it working:

```css
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------    Head    -------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*------------    Background    -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#banner{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 3, 3, 0.422),rgba(4, 3, 3, 0.422)) , url(pic/background.webp);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------------    Logo    -------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.logo{
    width: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1%;
    left: 5%;  
    z-index: 2;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*------------    Home / Text    ----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.banner_text{
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
.banner_text h1{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
    background: url(pic/text_background_new_low.png);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip:text;
    background-position: 0 200px;
    background-size: -20%;
    animation: back 20s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes back{
    100%{
        background-position: 3000px 0;
    }
}
.banner_text p{
    font-size: 15px;
    max-width: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------    Contact us Button    ------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.contact{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.contact a{
    width:190px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: black;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(to right  , gold 34%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.197) 65%)right;
    background-size: 300% 100%;
    background-position:right bottom;
    margin-left:10px;
    transition:all 1s ease;
    color: white;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.contact a:hover{
    background-position:left;
    color:black;  
}
.lover{
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-right: 15px;    
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------   EFFECTS   -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
.slide-left{
    animation: slide-left 1s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes slide-left{
    0% {
        transform: translate(100px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
#p.slide-left{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.contact.slide-left{
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*--------------   Navigation   -----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#sideNav{
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 20%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #0000007f;
}
.sideNav ul{
    width: 100%;
    height:10px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sideNav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 48px;
}
#sideNav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*----------   Navigation / Animation   ---------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#sideNav ul li a:hover{
    color: gold;
}
#sideNav ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #ffd700;
    display: block;
    margin: auto; 
    transition: 0.2s;
}
#sideNav ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffd700;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------   Hamburger Menu   ------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
#menuBtn{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index: 3;
    display: none;
}
#menuBtn img{
    width: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------   Responsive   ----------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width:770px){
    .sideNav ul{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 75px;
        right: 0;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    #sideNav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #sideNav ul li a{
        color: white;
    }
    .banner_text h1{
        font-size:70px;
    }
    .banner_text p{
        font-size: 13px;
    }
    #menuBtn{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Autohaus Kaya</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="zzzAutohaus_Kaya.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            html{
                scroll-behavior: smooth;
                scrollbar-width: normal;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="banner">
            <img src="pic/logo.png" class="logo">
            <div id="sideNav">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Über uns</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fahrzeuge</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Inzahlungnahme & Finanzierung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="menuBtn">
                <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FFw96Z.png&f=1&nofb=1">
            </div>
            <script>
                var menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
                var sideNav= document.getElementById("sideNav")
                var menu = document.getElementById("menu")

                menuBtn.onclick = function(){
                    if(sideNav.style.left == "800px"){
                        sideNav.style.left = "0";
                    }
                    else{
                        sideNav.style.left = "800px";
                    }
                }
            </script>
            <div class="banner_text slide-left">
                <h1>Willkommen</h1>
                <p class="slide-left">Gemeinsam finden wir Ihr passendes Wunschfahrzeug. Durch langjährige Erfahrung in der Automobilbranche wissen wir, 
                    worauf Sie Wert legen. Lassen Sie sich gerne bei einem Kalt - oder Warmgetränk überzeugen und vereinbaren Sie jetzt 
                    einen Termin.</p>
                <div class="contact slide-left">
                    <a href="#" class="lover">Kontaktieren Sie uns</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```